# Automatic re-rendering: confusion about reactiveness

Tags: meteor

Suppose I have a template called `Navbar` that is included in both `Main` and `About` pages. In the `Navbar` template, I have a search bar component that I want to show only on the `Main` template. I define a helper function like below:

```
Template.Navbar.helpers({
  'isMain': function() {
     return location.pathname == '/';
  }
})
```

And in the navbar.html,

```
{{#if isMain}}
  <div class="search">search</div>
{{/if}}
```

This works great as long as you **refresh** the page. It's because on the main page, `Navbar` template is already rendered and when you go to the `About` page, it doesn't get re-rendered. As a workaround, I am thinking of enclosing the helper function inside a `Template.autorun`.

**Q:** What exactly is happening here and what's the conventional way of dealing with this kind of problem? I am thinking of doing `Session.set("isMain", true)` everytime I go to mainpage.

Answer (score 3):

Your `isMain` template helper is not reactive, because it's not depending on any reactive data source (querying the location object, which is unreactive).

If you're using `iron:router` you could do something like :

```
Template.Navbar.helpers({
  'isMain': function() {
     return Router.current().route.getName() == 'main';
  }
});
```

Given that you've declared a main route as follow :

```
Router.route("/", {
  name: "main",
  [...]
});
```

If you're not using `iron:router`, you'd have to rely on something else, like a `Session` variable to track page change and set its value accordingly.

Comment: Although `Session` would work I feel like router seems more a natural way to deal with it. `Router.current().route.getName()` returns `undefined` though.

Comment: I think I should call the function inside 

```Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Main', {
    to: 'content'
  }); // Yield Main template to where {{> yield "content"}} is in layout.html
});```

but I can't find the context anywhere. Do you know?

Comment: `Router.current().route.getName()` returns `undefined` => pretty sure that's because you didn't gave a name to your route in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As @saimeunt suggested, I used Iron Router to fix the issue.

```
  Template.Nav.helpers({
    'isMainPage': function(e, template) {
      return (Router.current().location.get().path == '/');
    }
  })
```

The syntax was a little different but this works because `Router` works as a reactive source but `location.pathname` does not make the `isMainPage` helper reactive.

It is also possible to set `Session.set('isMain', true/false)` every time you go navigate to/from the main page and the helper  returns `Session.get('isMain')`